# GetFeatureInfo from Image WMS

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have a problem with GetFeatureInfo (I'm working with openlayers). 
In my HTML file I have this:

```
  <div id="map" class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Sieraków <span class="badge badge-secondary">MAPA</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="info"></div>
```

And I want to show some info in div #info. 
In javascript I have layer from geoserver:

```
var theurl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sierakow/wms';
    var jeziora = new ol.layer.Image({
          source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: theurl,
            params: {'LAYERS': 'sierakow:jeziora'},
            serverType: 'geoserver'
          })
    });
    map.addLayer(jeziora);

    map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
            var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
            var url = jeziora.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
              evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:4326',
              {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50});
            if (url) {
              document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
                  '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
            }
    });
```

To do this I followed this examples: [LINK](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html)
I also try [THIS ONE](http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch08-interacting-with-your-map/example-04.html) with parsing but result is the same, nothing happend. My div #info is still empty and I don't know why.

Console show me this errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jeziora.getGetFeatureInfoUrl is not a function

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

This is url:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sierakow/wms?SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.3.0
&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo
&FORMAT=image%2Fpng
&TRANSPARENT=true
&QUERY_LAYERS=sierakow%3Ajeziora
&LAYERS=sierakow%3Ajeziora
&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml
&FEATURE_COUNT=50
&I=50
&J=50
&CRS=EPSG%3A4326
&STYLES
&WIDTH=101
&HEIGHT=101
&BBOX=6919511.668971639%2C1779979.5230483634%2C6921441.703935839%2C1781909.558012564
```

And this error shows:

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sierakow/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=sierakow%3Ajeziora&LAYERS=sierakow%3Ajeziora&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fplain&FEATURE_COUNT=50&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=6918701.436880034%2C1786965.867550262%2C6920631.4718442345%2C1788895.9025144626' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

I will be greatful for every tips how to do that :)

Comment: please edit your question with details of the request sent to the server and the response that is sent back.

Comment: var url = jeziora.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(

Comment: Presumably you are not running the html from port 8080 so it's a cross origin issue.  Either use the same port for everything or add
`crossOrigin: 'Anonymous',` to the source options and ensure the WMS server returns an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` header.

Comment: I'm surprised you get any output considering CRS is EPSG::4326 expecting values +/-180 and BBOX has values far in excess of this 6919511.668971639%2C1779979.5230483634%2C6921441.703935839%2C1781909.558012564

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all your help! This is the solution:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
         document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
         var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
         var url = jeziora.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
           evt.coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
           {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json', 'propertyName': 'nam'});
           if (url) {
            var parser = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
            $.ajax({
              url: url,
              dataType: 'json',
              jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse'
            }).then(function(response) {
              var result = parser.readFeatures(response);
              if (result.length) {
                var inf = [];
                for (var i = 0, ii = result.length; i < ii; ++i) {
                  inf.push(result[i].get('nam'));
                }
                 document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = inf.join(', ');
              } else {
                 document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
              }
            });
          }
      });
```